# Working with multiple audio players

Tags: javascript, php, audio

I am trying to let all audio players,play there song when the play button is pushed. But I keep getting the error audio cannot read property 'attr' of null. I use a for loop to get my data from the database , the next step was  to use the data in the audio player.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    let isPlaying = false;
    $('.player-button').click(function() {
        let song = document.querySelector(".player").attr('data-id');
        let button = document.querySelector(".toggle");
        $('.toggle').attr('data-id');
        if (isPlaying == false){
            song.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            button.innerHTML ='<i class="fa fa-pause fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        } else {
            song.pause();
            isPlaying = false;
            button.innerHTML ='<i class="fa fa-play fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        }
        console.log($(this));
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="MusicItem">

  <img src="<?php echo $arrayMusic[0][$i][" image "] ?>">

  <div class="music-player">
<button class="player-button toggle" title="togglePlay"><i class="fa fa-play fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" data id="<?php echo$i?>"></i></button>

<div class="MusicText">
  <h2>
    <?php echo $arrayMusic[0][$i]["title"] ?>
  </h2>
  <p>
    <?php echo $arrayMusic[0][$i]["theYear"] ?>
  </p>
</div>

<audio class="player<?php echo$i?>">
                            <source src="<?php echo $arrayMusic[0][$i]["track"] ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
                        </audio>

  </div>
  <div class="MusicButtons">
<button class="MusicInfo">Info</button>
<button class="MusicBuy"><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/malvae/id986932690" target="_blank">Buy</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are mixing up jquery and non-jquery code. Does your page include jQuery?

Comment: yes it does in the header.php file

Comment: Use the debugger of your browser to step through your code and observe every line. Check that every statement does exactly what you intended, the error message leads me to the line `$('.toggle').attr('data-id');`. Your toggle does not even have an attribute "data-id".